# Hide taxonomy terms when using Taxonomy Access Control Lite

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I'm using the [Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) module to make certain pages/nodes visible only to people with certain roles.  That's working fine.

However, a side effect seems to be that now at the bottom of each node, the tagging I'm using for marking nodes as Private/Public is shown to the user.  My taxonomy is called "Access Level", so the bottom of each page now says either "Access Level: Private" or "Access Level: Public".

What's a good way to hide those?  I feel like it probably has something to do with the "Visibility" checkbox, but I don't really understand what that box is saying.